# Coupon with 3 different % discounts based on Categories

Tags: php

In Woocommerce, I would like to have a single coupon that offers multiple % discounts depending on the category that the product is in. I have 3 Categories

- 35OFF - 35% Off
- 15OFF - 15% Off
- 10OFF - 10% Off

This is what I've got so far (taken and adapted from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512397/coupon-with-2-different-percentage-discounts-based-on-product-category-in-woocom) that's a few years old).

EDIT: UPDATE. PHP Code is now accepted by Wordpress, but doesn't apply the discounts to anything

` function alter_shop_coupon_data( $round, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'alter_shop_coupon_data', 20, 5 );
```

function alter_shop_coupon_data( $round, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){

```
## ---- Your settings ---- ##

// Related coupons codes to be defined in this array (you can set many)
```

( $coupon_codes = array('HLUK2021'))

```
// Product categories at 15% (IDs, Slugs or Names)  for 15% of discount
($product_category15 = array('15OFF')); // for 15% discount

$second_percentage = 0.15; // 15 %

// Product categories at 35% (IDs, Slugs or Names)  for 35% of discount
$product_category35 = array('35OFF'); // for 35% discount

$third_percentage = 0.35 // 35%;


## ---- The code: Changing the percentage to 20% for specific a product category ---- ##
    
    ;

if ( $coupon->is_type('percent') && in_array( $coupon->get_code(), $coupon_codes ) ) {
    if( has_term( $product_category20, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
        $original_coupon_amount = (float) $coupon->get_amount();
        $discount = $original_coupon_amount * $second_percentage * $discounting_amount;
        $round15 = round( min( $discount, $discounting_amount ), wc_get_rounding_precision());

if ( $coupon->is_type('percent') && in_array( $coupon->get_code(), $coupon_codes ) ) {
    if( has_term( $product_category35, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
        $original_coupon_amount = (float) $coupon->get_amount();
        $discount = $original_coupon_amount * $third_percentage * $discounting_amount;
        $round35 = round( min( $discount, $discounting_amount ), wc_get_rounding_precision() );
    
        $round = $round15 + round35;

return $round;
}}}}}`
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: Sorry, I was banging my head against the wall all day yesterday.

Is the code correct? It seems to not be working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Please show a [mre].

Comment: That's my problem I cant produce an MRE When I try and add the code to the PHP Editor i get this: (comment below this one)

So I'm obviously incorrect in thinking I can run a second IF calculation after the first one

Comment: ` Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 38 of file wp-content/themes/shoppingcart/woocommerce/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: First of all, I think there are some unmatched parentheses or curly braces in the code you have shown (use a decent editor which highlights matching pairs of parentheses to debug this); and then, while I don't know PHP well, I think `AND if` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay so this pointed me more in the right direction. I can't find a code editor that's highlighting any parentheses that aren't matched up though, everything is saying it should run except when it's put into the website it doesn't work - Edited question with new code

Comment: for an MRE www.herbal-living.co.uk - website PHP code is currently installed on.

Searching for TEST PRODUCT will find products in all the correct categories

Comment: Vim and Visual Studio Code are editors which highlight matching pairs of parentheses, for example.